# Does the GCM Server API key expire?

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I am facing a problem in GCM. Initially, the application was working perfectly, but after some time it stopped working.

So I changed my Server API key, then it started working again. Now, I'm experiencing it again. I can't receive notifications.

So I wanted to ask, does the Server API key expire or is there some other problem?

Comment: Server API key never expires (until you change), it seems to be other issue

Answer (score 0):

The API key never expires, but if you have changed it you should be changing your Tokens to send the notification. To generate a Token inside an app you need to use GCM project id, which is linked to that API key, so just a server using that key and token will be able to send pushes to that app.
I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Android client key will expires after 7days, you can get the expire time by call this method:

```
        long serverLifeSpan = GCMRegistrar.getRegisterOnServerLifespan(this);
```

the result will be 7days, so after 7days, the android client must be register gcm again or you can't receive gcm message,because the previous client gcm token invalid.

the better way is to register each time the app is launched.