# Is it possible to call GCM expire time in javascript

Tags: javascript, android, google-cloud-messaging

In my phonegap application i like to call this function, where i should this piece of code whether inside the receiver or inside third party plugin

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18072720/1482099

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no reason to call this function.

You should be aware that `GCMRegistrar` is deprecated. In addition, the `getRegisterOnServerLifespan` wasn't very useful even when it wasn't deprecated.

BTW, that method has nothing to do with the question that the answer in your link was supposed to answer. It returns an arbitrary time period after which the registration ID is considered expired, while the question was about expiration of the API key.

Comment: Thanks for your response. What i need is to track the expire time of the user and if token get expires the client should request for new token. This is possible ?